# Magento 2.3 How add additional links in tag <head>?

Tags: magento2, html, page, head

[image]

How to add information to the tag, please tell me?! I want to add .phtml file

I can change the class along this path and add this way, but it seems to me that there is another way

> Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page

In the method **render**
And I know about way in admin panel Magento:

> https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/html-head.html

[image]

But I want to find a way how I can add data without changing this code.